# tensorflow dropout - requires weight normalization after changing to keep probability of 1?

Tags: tensorflow

Id like to use dropout to improve my model's final prediction accuracy. 
To my understanding :
1) Using drop out we randomly assign neurons to zero.
2) Thereby in the next layer the neuron's values are dependent only on a subset of the previous layers neurons. 
3) Therefore during training the neurons's weights are trained to be stronger than they should be ( inversely proportional to drop out rate ) to compensate for the 'droped' neurons in the previous layer. 
4) After training when we want to use all of the neurons without dropout we need to compensate by multiplying the neurons in each layer by (1-dropout rate).
 

Am I correct? And if so does tf.nn.dropout() take care of this or do I need to do it manually?  

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do perform dropout, random neurons are chosen in that layer and their weights are made 0. When the model is trained, you get two outputs, the architecture of your model and a h5 file that consists of weights. After the training is done, you save these files in your storage and can load anytime for prediction. You do not have to multiply add weight to any neuron manually. TF takes care of it.